# Does AWS have any PUSH mechanism to Django?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

For example, once a job is done at AWS side, are there any systems/mechanisms which notify Django that the job is done and Django can do the next thing? Looks like SNS is one. Are there any better solutions? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'AWS side'? give an example as on a normal django setup, there is really nothing on the AWS side. And Django is not a thing, so I am guessing you mean 'notify the server'. Django can be running as a server and as a worker. So, an example or description of your architecture will help.

Comment: Thanks, Davka. I am trying to build an mobile app, which can (interactively) visualize the data processed by server side. I prefer to using the components in AWS to deal with the storage and processing (please let me know if you have better solutions). It looks like AWS can talk to client side (mobile apps) directly through, for example, S3 mobile APIs. If I put Django in-between AWS and mobile client, after Django receives the request from the client side and passes the request to AWS, how can Django know that AWS has completed the process and the data are ready to sent to the client side?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at Celery for doing server/worker architectures, but here are a few tips to consider which may answer some of your questions:

- For S3, look into something like fine-uploader or implement this yourself where you will have the client (mobile) get a signed URL from the server, then use that to upload the files directly to S3, and when done, will make another call to the server to record the fact that the upload was completed. The alternative is to use something like AWS SNS or AWS Lambda which you can configure S3 to trigger when the file is uploaded. The Lambda function could then write directly to your database to make a call to your API to record the completeness
- Several of the AWS services trigger SNS or SQS which you can use to notify you. I would recommend putting a Lambda function to parse the SNS and then make deal with it (as I said, even calling your HTTP API)
- In general, you can just have something like celery such that the server can just delay the heavy processing for the worker to deal with. On the worker side, you can use BOTO and just call into AWS functions and just wait for them to complete.

In short, implement your own server/worker architecture, or use SNS, SQS and Lambda to push as much functionality to AWS.

As an example, in my server, I allow users to upload pictures for their profile (and other objects). I use fine-uploaded to upload the pictures directly to S3, requiring very little computer power on my server (other than signing the URL at the beginning). I then have the S3 automatically trigger a Lambda function which I use to create a thumbnail and then I write the file to another bucket, which then triggers another Lambda function which I use to create a tiny thumbnail, and upload it to a third bucket. All of this happens on the 'AWS side' as you say. I don't even bother notifying the server as the server simply tries to find the thumbnail picture when needed, and if not find, just renders the larger picture (or a static no-thumnail.png picture).

Your question is too open ended to be answered so I hope you got something useful from this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, davka. Very helpful!